# How to interpret "from . import function_name"?

Tags: python

Inside `numpy.fft._pocketfft.py` you can find `import commands` like:

```
from . import _pocketfft_internal as pfi
```

How would I interpret this line?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` means from **current package**. Hence, this line means:

```
from . import _pocketfft_internal as pfi
```

Import `_pocketfft_internal` from current package, you should be able to see a file named `_pocketfft_internal.py` in the current directory. You can study more about this from [here](https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/import.html#tok-relative_module)

Comment: That was exactly what I wanted to know. Thank you. Will accept as answer in 12 minutes.